# How to access same element in multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript

I tried this:

in `constant.js`

```
const CONFIRM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".confirm-button");
export { CONFIRM_BUTTON };
```

in some-file.js,

```
import { CONFIRM_BUTTON } from './constants';
CONFIRM_BUTTON.onclick = someFunction;
```

I am getting `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` error in doing so.

If in some-file.js file, I do following, it works:

```
const CONFIRM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".confirm-button");
CONFIRM_BUTTON.onclick = someFunction;
```

I am trying to do this `const CONFIRM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".confirm-button");`  once and use it multiple js files? How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure the selector is being evaluated after the DOM is ready? If the DOM is not ready when the `document.querySelector(...)` is evaluated, it will return `null`.

Comment: `.confirm-button` in not in the DOM on initial load, but instead of importing CONFIRM_BUTTON element, if I declare it in the same file and use it, it works. This works ` const CONFIRM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".confirm-button");

Answer (score 1):

you need just `export CONFIRM_BUTTON`  without curved brackets

Comment: I get `Declaration or statement expected` error in doing so;  
`const CONFIRM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".confirm-button");  
export CONFIRM_BUTTON;`

Comment: have you tried to use `const CONFIRM_BUTTON = 
 document.getElementsByClassName("confirm-button")` ?